# How does the keydown event work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want that if my input text value is not empty then show my `.removetext` div but it doesn't work properly. If you type a something after second character my `.removetext` is being hidden but if my input is not empty don't hide my `.removetext` class.

Where is my mistake? I guess I don't understand the keydown event

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.search-hotels').on('input', function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value);
    if (!val == "") {
      $(".removetext").show(val.length > 0, function() {
        var clear = $(this);
        clear.on('click', function() {
          alert('hey');
        })
      });
    } else {
      $(".removetext").hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
}

.search-hotels {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
}

.removetext {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 25%;
  font-size: 23px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <input type="text" class="search-hotels">
  <div class="removetext">&times;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity how the heck does `$(el).show(function)` work?  I don't see that in the docs for [jQuery.show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)  I assume it's using the `.show(duration, complete)` pattern, can anyone confirm?

Comment: Likely a test - if only one argument and argument is a function, use it as callback

Comment: If you add `$(".removetext").show(val.length > 0, function() {
        var clear = $(this);
        clear.on('click', function() {
          alert('hey');
        })` then for EVERY keystroke, you add an event handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try input - it handles paste too:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.search-hotels').on('input', function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.value);
    $(".removetext").toggle(val.length>0); // test anything not blank
  });
  // the event handler needs to be HERE and not inside the inout handler
  $(".removetext").on('click', function() {
      alert('hey');
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
}

.search-hotels {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
}

.removetext {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 25%;
  font-size: 23px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <input type="text" class="search-hotels" value="">
  <div class="removetext">&times;</div>
</div>
```

If you need a callback you do need show and hide

```js
$(function() {
  $('.search-hotels').on('input', function() {
    var show = $.trim(this.value).length>0;
    if (show) {
      $(".removetext").show("slow",function() {
        console.log("showing");
      });
    }
    else {
      $(".removetext").hide("slow",function() {
        console.log("hiding");
      });
    }
        
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
}

.search-hotels {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
}

.removetext {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 25%;
  font-size: 23px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <input type="text" class="search-hotels" value="">
  <div class="removetext">&times;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the first time that I've seen if statement in toggle function thank you so much!

Comment: another question does toggle has callback ? for example .toggle(val.length>0,function(){//callback})

Comment: No. If you need to have a callback, you need show and hide

Comment: yes I need to add click event after my `.removetext` being is showed to clear input this doesn't work:     $(".removetext").show(val.length>0,function(){
            alert('showed');
        });

Comment: thanks mplungjan.I set click event for my removetext class but it is not work I guess callback is working but click event is not

Comment: I have no idea - your code does not show any click code

Comment: Please see my update. Absolutely no need to assign a click handler in a callback. Just have it in the page ready event !

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve what you want by using `keyup` instead of `keydown` and changing your `if` statement to the following:

```
if ($(this).val());
```

Using `keydown` means that it will not use the `.val` that was input but will check the `.val` before the input is updated because the `.val` will be updated *after* the `keyup`  event.

> **An even better approach would be to use the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) as follows:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.search-hotels').on('input', function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      $(".removetext").show(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
      });
    } else {
      $(".removetext").hide();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
}

.search-hotels {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
}

.removetext {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 25%;
  font-size: 23px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <input type="text" class="search-hotels">
  <div class="removetext">&times;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this because the input cannot be registered on the moment the key is pressed?

Comment: Yes I agree input is better ;)

Answer (score 2):

Keydown event is fired before a character is typed, hence you should use keyup event which is fired after the character is typed.

Also, `!$(this).val()` is different than `$(this).val()==""`

Use `if($(this).val()=="")`

Answer (score 1):

You should use keyup. Key down registers the key pressed but it hasn't populated the input yet. You can either go through the keydown event properties and use the property "key" (if i remember correctly) to get the value entered during the keydown, but if you want to grab the text in the input, you'll need "keyup"

Answer (score 1):

you can use `keyup` here better and checking for `$(this).val().length` would be better.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.search-hotels').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
      $(".removetext").show(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
      });
    } else {
      $(".removetext").hide();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
}

.search-hotels {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
}

.removetext {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 25%;
  font-size: 23px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <input type="text" class="search-hotels">
  <div class="removetext">&times;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `if ($(this).val())` otherwise your checking if it's empty.
Also, use `keyup` as `keydown` is capturing your `val()` before it actually has a value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.search-hotels').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      $(".removetext").show(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
      });
    } else {
      $(".removetext").hide();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
}

.search-hotels {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
}

.removetext {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 25%;
  font-size: 23px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <input type="text" class="search-hotels">
  <div class="removetext">&times;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

keydown event fires when the button is pressed, at that moment your value isn't updated, try using keyup event fires when the button is released and the input value is updated...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.search-hotels').on('keyup', function() {
    console.log(this,$(this).val());
    if ($(this).val()) {
      $(".removetext").show(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
      });
    } else {
      $(".removetext").hide();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
}

.search-hotels {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
}

.removetext {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 25%;
  font-size: 23px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <input type="text" class="search-hotels">
  <div class="removetext">&times;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use keydown event because it is one keypress "behind" of what's written into input `value`.

Ideally you should use `oninput` (not even keyup as suggested by everyone, but @mplungjan who was faster :). [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) will also allow you to properly track copy/past events unlike onkeyup.

In addition, read input value by simply `this.value` but remember to trim it also to get rid of whitespaces.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.search-hotels').on('input', function() {
    if (this.value.trim()) {
      $(".removetext").show();
    } else {
      $(".removetext").hide();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
}

.search-hotels {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
}

.removetext {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 25%;
  font-size: 23px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <input type="text" class="search-hotels">
  <div class="removetext">&times;</div>
</div>
```